# Typescript class method ONLY if generic type is string

Tags: typescript, class, methods, typescript-generics

Using a generic typed class, I would like some methods to be available **ONLY IF** generic type is 'string'.

With the following code

```js
class MyClass<T = string> {
  value: T = null;

  setDate(m: Moment) {
    // could be used only if T is string
    value = m ? m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') : null;
  }

}
```

gives me the error

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'
```

which is really clear and totally intended : `Moment.format()` returns a `string`. :D

Is there a proper way to make the `setDate()` method avaible only if `T` is `string` ?

By advance, thank you very much.

---

I know I can fix the problem using `m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') as unknown as T` but it looks like a workaround, not a real typescript solution.

And I know about Conditional Types but I don't think it could fix my problem. At least, I did not find how to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

make function have `never` arg on incorrect generic

```
type Moment = {format(s:string):string};

type SimpleEquals<T, V> = [T] extends [V] ? [V] extends [T] ? true : false : false;


class MyClass<T = string> {
  value: T | null = null;

    // could be used only if T is string
  setDate(m: SimpleEquals<T, string> extends true ? Moment : never) {
    this.value = m ? m.format('YYYY-MM-DD') as T : null;
  }
}

declare let m: Moment; 

new MyClass<string>().setDate(m) // ok

new MyClass<number>().setDate() //err
new MyClass<number>().setDate(m) //err

new MyClass<string | number>().setDate() //err
new MyClass<string | number>().setDate(m) //err

new MyClass<'qwe'>().setDate() //err
new MyClass<'qwe'>().setDate(m) //err
```